# FreeBSD11: Certificate verification failed

Tags: freebsd

My FreeBSD 11 gives:

```
[root@freebsd11 ~]# pkg install perl
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
Certificate verification failed for /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
34406394360:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1269:
Certificate verification failed for /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
34406394360:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1269:
Certificate verification failed for /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
34406394360:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1269:
Certificate verification failed for /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
34406394360:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1269:
Certificate verification failed for /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
34406394360:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1269:
Certificate verification failed for /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
34406394360:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1269:
pkg: https://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/meta.txz: Authentication error
repository FreeBSD has no meta file, using default settings
Certificate verification failed for /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
34406394360:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1269:
Certificate verification failed for /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
34406394360:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1269:
Certificate verification failed for /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
34406394360:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1269:
pkg: https://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/packagesite.pkg: Authentication error
Certificate verification failed for /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
34406394360:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1269:
Certificate verification failed for /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
34406394360:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1269:
Certificate verification failed for /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
34406394360:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1269:
pkg: https://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/packagesite.txz: Authentication error
Unable to update repository FreeBSD
Error updating repositories!
```

I think this is caused by an expired certificate, but I have no idea on how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replied to you [GitHub issue](https://github.com/lavabit/robox/issues/266) already, but see [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lavabit/robox/e826ca93a9313dbdf49233dd6ca9155e565539c5/scripts/freebsd11/pkg.sh) script for how to update the ca-bundle file on your system. This particular script uses the Mozilla CA repository as its source, and updates the following files.

/etc/ssl/cert.pem
/usr/local/openssl/cert.pem
/usr/local/etc/ssl/cert.pem
/usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt

Depending on what you have installed, you might have other bundle files elsewhere on your file system that need to also be updated.

Comment: Yep: This seems to fix it: `parallel 'scp vagrant@freebsd12:{} vagrant@freebsd11:/tmp; ssh vagrant@freebsd11 sudo cp /tmp/{/} {}' ::: /etc/ssl/cert.pem  /usr/local/openssl/cert.pem  /usr/local/etc/ssl/cert.pem  /usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the DST Root CA X3 cert historically used by Let's Encrypt expired a year and a half ago; see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/ and as linked there https://letsencrypt.org/2020/12/21/extending-android-compatibility.html . (We had about a hundred Qs on several Stacks -- to my recollection unix, apple, security, SF, SU, SO, and maybe more -- most within a week or two but some tailing in after 2 or 3 months; were you vacationing off-planet?)

Check what version of OpenSSL (program: do `openssl version`) and ca_root_nss (package) you have. If your root-CAs are older than about 2017 you probably don't have the ISRG root in your trustfile (probably /usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt supplied by the package) and need to add it -- probably you'll need to  download to a newer system and then copy to your derelict one; it must be in PEM format, but if you get DER just use `openssl x509 -inform der -outform pem <this >that` to convert it, optionally adding `-text -fingerprint` to get the helpful human-readable prologue.

If your OpenSSL is below 1.1.0 and you have the now-obosolete DST-X3 root in the trustfile, which you almost certainly do for a system built before 2020, you need to remove that (with any handy editor) to avoid the OpenSSL bug mentioned by the LE page.

As always save a backup of any critical file before modifying it. And once you get your system working, look if there's an official ca_root_nss update with these changes and if so use it instead of a hand patch.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the commands to run? E.g. "probably you'll need to download to a newer system" Download which URL to where? And: "look if there's an official ca_root_nss update with these changes and if so use it instead of a hand patch." I have the feeling you know exactly how to do this, but your answer does not show the commands to run to do this. Maybe assume I have installed FreeBSD for the first time ever.

Comment: You should also feel free to link to these other questions if they explain how to fix it on FreeBSD 11. However, if the questions just mention the certificate expired and that "you need to take precautions", then they do not answer this question. This question is about how you in practice take these precautions on FreeBSD 11.

Comment: Ole: in general I'm a fan of linking or closing dupes (for a fairly extreme example see https://security.stackexchange.com/a/159289) and I tried several I had bookmarked for this issue but: none were directly for FreeBSD, some were for other OSes and needed changes, and most were for application levels (nodejs, python, PHP) and needed even more changes, so finally I just wrote from scratch. The existing As don't 'just [say] take precautions', they say what to add (ISRGX1) and remove (DSTX3), as I did, but _how_ to do that varies depending on what you're doing it to ...

Comment: ... and I don't use 11 at all and last used 10 enough years ago for many details to have blurred, so I described the parts I could be sure of and left the rest open. The ISRG root cert is linked right near the top of the LE page I referenced -- which itself uses an LE cert and thus is only reachable from an up-to-date system or browser.